# How to make SVG resize in a div inside flexbox?

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, flexbox

My task is to make the SVG resize according to the size of the flexbox.

If I remove the `<div>` that is the parent of `<svg>`, the SVG scales properly; however, I cannot do that because there needs to be a sibling of `<svg>`

I have tried flex-grow, flex-shrink, using height, max-height, but all of them don't work for me and I am stumped.

To clarify, the bottom part with `#console` should be fixed height (or not going below specific height).
The top part with `#shape` should be resized according to the remaining height. A lot of things were drawn in 1000x500 viewbox so changing viewbox is not viable too.

#### The HTML (I use Vue here but I don't think it matters)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="shape">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
            <polygon points="200,100 200,400 800,400 800,100" style="fill:lime" />
        </svg>
        <div style="position: absolute">I wanted to put something here to be the same size of this flexbox, so I need to wrap the SVG inside the div.</div>
  </div>
      <div id="console">
        Some fixed height item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

## The CSS

```
<style>
  #main {
    height: 95vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  #shape {

  }
  #console {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

Or see it here in Codepen: https://codepen.io/kritsada_stw/pen/xxZowQX

Comment: _My task is to make the SVG resize according to the size of the flexbox._ It does. Just add a border or a background to the svg to see it.

Comment: The expected result is that the bottom div should be 600px, while the top div should just consume the remaining space. Does that make sense?

Comment: delete the height of the main and give  #shape  a height